# error processing catkin package gt_gui_cpp

Tags: ros, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to build the catkin workspace on fedora 23 . I am following instructions given here
[Installation/Source-ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source). Under the section 2.1.3 Building the Catkin Workspace, for the command-

> $
> ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated
> --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

My command line session shows the following :

> == Finished processing package [79 of 228]: 'pluginlib'
>
> ==> Processing catkin package: 'qt_gui_cpp'
> ==> Building with env: '/home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
> Makefile exists, skipping explicit
> cmake invocation...
> ==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
>
> ==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
> [ 83%] Built target qt_gui_cpp [ 88%]
> Running SIP generator for
> qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py",
> line 47, in 
> config = Configuration()   File "/home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py",
> line 16, in **init**
> ['qmake', '-query'], env=env, universal_newlines=True)   File
> "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 566, in check_output
> process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)   Fi
> le
> "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 710, in **init**
> errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 1335, in _execute_child
> No such file or directory
> src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:89:
> recipe for target
> 'sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile' failed
> make[2]: ***
> [sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:374: recipe for
> target
> 'src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all'
> failed make[1]: ***
> [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all]
> Error 2
>
> Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all'
> failed make: *** [all] Error 2 <==
> Failed to process package
> 'qt_gui_cpp':    Command
> '['/home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh',
> 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned
> non-zero exit status 2
> Reproduce this error by running:
> ==> cd /home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp
> &&
> /home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh
> make -j4 -l4
>
> Command failed, exiting.

I am not able to understand the next thing to do, I tried

> $ cd /home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp
> &&
> /home/tshrotriya/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh
> make -j4 -l4

But that didn't do much either.Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249980/error-processing-catkin-package-gt_gui_cpp/) by [Tanisha12](https://answers.ros.org/users/28789/tanisha12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason for this error is, as mentioned in the error message, is missing file. Actually it cannot find `qmake`.
If you try executing qmake from command line it will not find this command.
Check what qmake varians you have by tab-completing it in the command line. Personally i had `qmake-qt4` and `qmake-qt5`. Here I assume, that since you got this far in the build process, you have all required qt5 packages installed.
To fix this issue:

1. Find location of the `qmake-qt5` by running the command `which qmake-qt5` (in my case it was `/usr/bin/qmake-qt5`)
2. Run command `sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/qmake qmake /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 1` (substitute path to `qmake-qt5` with yours from previous step)

---

Originally posted by [spooner-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/29765/spooner-dev/) with karma: 151 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1